# symfony2 logout after a period of inactivity

Tags: symfony

I got a Symfony2 (2.0.9) project and the B-Office part I do not understand where is set the idle time ?
identification generates a good session cookie "PHPSESSID" equal to the variable (config.yml) framework:session:lifetime:86400 (one day)  BUT I'm automatically disconnected after an hour !

Comment: Not sure if you are still having struggle with this... but at the end the gc_maxlifetime did not work for me... so I did this: https://github.com/bvisonl/inactivity-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did You check session lifetime on the server ? See [the documentation for session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime). The default value is:

```
 session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Which means 24 minutes.