# Symfony2 Prevent Auto Logout

Tags: php, symfony

Is there anyway in Symfony2 to prevent the system from auto logging someone out. Mine Symfony2 app seems to be logging someone out after just an hour of inactivity. I want something much like Facebook where you never have to log back in once you are authenticated or unless you logout. Here is my current security.yml code block

```
login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony2 logout after a period of inactivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828796/symfony2-logout-after-a-period-of-inactivity)

Comment: Check the session `lifetime`

Comment: you must not restart your webserver

Answer (score 1):

check your parameters for the session, what is set there? it should be in **config.yml**, set the bigger values, and your issue will be gone:

```
#app/config/config.yml
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 86400
    gc_maxlifetime: 1800
```

More information could be found in [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection).

Comment: This is what I currently have: session: handler_id:  ~, Ill add what you've provided.

Comment: What does the value 1800 represent in terms of hours/days etc?

Comment: It's 1800 seconds, so 30 min.

Comment: @LargeTuna, you may reference the official documentation. The values are in seconds. A cookie lifetime of 0 means the cookie expires when the browser is closed. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection