# How can I prevent automatic logout for users in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, session, config

I try to prevent the automatic logout for users in Symfony.
According to this post [Symfony2 Prevent Auto Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461274/symfony2-prevent-auto-logout)

I am trying to change my code like this:

```
   #app/config/config.yml
     session:
     cookie_lifetime: 86400
     gc_maxlifetime: 1800
```

The problem is, that in my Symfony I cannot find a config.yml

my config folder looks like this:

```
config
  packages
  routes
  bundles.php
  routes.yaml
  services.yaml
```

Comment: Isn't the article you linked to the opposite of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Now I added the correct article

Comment: You are looking at an article from Symfony2 and using Symfony5 (probably). The framework has evolved over time quite a lot (especially between 2 and 3 and then 3 and 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the cookies lifetime for all project at the `config/packages/framework.yaml` or for only production (for better developing without login all the time) at the `config/packages/prod/framework.yaml`. Both under the session key as the linked article suggest.